# Laravel how to check for duplicate records before inserting into Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I am using .csv files for bank statement records that I want to import into mySQL using Laravel, however I want to validate the records to check for duplications. I have created a "checkrow" field below which is a combination of the fields from the .csv file.

```
   while (($record = fgetcsv($input_file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                {
                    if (!$heading)
                    {
                        $product = array(
                            "checkrow" => "ABSA" . $record['0'] . $record['1'] . $record['2'] . $record['3'],
                            "bankname" => "ABSA",
                            "accountnumber" => "123456",
                            "trnDate" => $record['0'],
                            "description" => $record['1']  ,
                            "reference" => self::getAbsaReference($record['1'] ) ,
                            "amount" => $record['2']
                             
                        );
                        print_r ($product);
                        
                        BankStatement::create($product);    
                    }
                    $heading = false;
                }
```

When I run the "BankStatement::create($product); " to update table, I have a row in the mysql table called "checkrow" (which updates from the 'checkrow' field above) which is unique in mysql (does not allow duplicates), however when I run this code it gives a "***Integrity constraint violation"*** which is exactly what its supposed to be doing.

However, I would like it to skip this row in the .csv file and move onto the next to insert to mysql when it identifies a duplicate.

Comment: use Upserts  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts

Comment: Wow as simple as that , thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`updateOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts)

```
BankStatement::updateOrCreate([
    'checkrow' => "ABSA" . $record['0'] . $record['1'] . $record['2'] . $record['3'],
], [
    "bankname" => "ABSA",
    "accountnumber" => "123456",
    "trnDate" => $record['0'],
    "description" => $record['1']  ,
    "reference" => self::getAbsaReference($record['1'] ) ,
    "amount" => $record['2']
]);
```

> As well alternative version `upsert()` which introduced in Laravel 8+

Comment: be aware that update or create first does a select and then an insert (2 queries).  Upsert does an insert and if that fails it does an update. So when the record does not exist it only executes one query.

Comment: @Snapey ***Note that `Upsert` is only available after Laravel 8.*** What can we do on the lower version of Laravel? Still, we have to use it, right? Also, OP doesn't mention the Larvel version, which he uses. So It can't be specific because this helps future readers too.

Comment: Lower versions are not supported.  Upgrade.

Comment: @Snapey, wow, genius. I will tell everyone to do it.

Comment: Please do.  My comment was to alert the OP to the benefit of using upsert and therefore yet another good reason to upgrade if they are running on an old, unsupported version.